# Reverse recursive in array to find parent id

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, parent

Trying to figure out a way of getting the parent ID of an item in a multi dimensional array:

```
$Arr = array(
    array(
        "Id" => 1,
        "Parent" => 0,
        "Children" => array(
            array(
                "Id" => 2,
                "Parent" => 1,
                "Children" => array(),
            ),
            array(
                "Id" => 3,
                "Parent" => 1,
                "Children" => array(
                    array(
                        "Id" => 4,
                        "Parent" => 3,
                        "Children" => array(),
                    ),  
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ), 
    array(
        "Id" => 5,
        "Parent" => 0,
        "Children" => array(
            array(
                "Id" => 6,
                "Parent" => 5,
                "Children" => array(),
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

I need to get the "Id" for the top element where "Parent" = 0. I.e. for the item with Id 4 it should return 1 as result, or a search for 6 would return 5. I have tried various ways of recursive function but only manage to get the correct result when the depth is 2.

I have found this function but it seems to return the name of the key rather than the value:

```
function find_parent($array, $needle, $parent = null) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $pass = $parent;
            if (is_string($key)) {
                $pass = $key;
            }
            $found = find_parent($value, $needle, $pass);
            if ($found !== false) {
                return $found;
            }
        } else if ($key === 'Id' && $value === $needle) {
            return $parent;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

### Edit

The following only works on the 1st level/depth:

```
function GetParent($Data = array(), $Needle = 0){
    foreach($Data as $Key => $Item){
        if($Item['Id'] === $Needle && $Item['Parent'] == 0){
            return $Item['Id'];             
        }
        if(sizeof($Item['Children']) !== 0)
            GetParent($Item['Children'], $Item['Parent']);

    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Instead of going through all keys, who don't you just check sub-values something like `if ($arr['Id'] == $needle) { return $arr['Parent']; }`

Comment: What do you want to return?

Comment: @Duvdevan: I would like to return the value of "Id" for the parent element. If searching for 6 the function should return 5, if searching for 4 it should return 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is not usually speed efficient, but PHP has a really great feature in the [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)  called [Iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php). Anong them you can find [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) which saves you from writing the recursive functions for yourself. In you case, you have to redefine two of its methods:

```
class CustomRecursiveIterator extends RecursiveArrayIterator
{
    public function hasChildren() {
        return !empty($this->current()['Children']) && is_array($this->current()['Children']);
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return new static($this->current()['Children']);
    }
}
```

Doing so, you can be sure that you will loop over children, but not all array elements.

Given this class you can write function that will suit your needs:

```
function getParentId($id, array $array)
{
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new CustomRecursiveIterator($array),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST 
    );

    $childFound = false;
    foreach ($iterator as $item) {
        if (
            $childFound
            && isset($item['Parent'])
            && $item['Parent'] === 0
            && isset($item['Id'])
        ) {
            return $item['Id'];
        }

        if (isset($item['Id']) && $item['Id'] === $id) {
            $childFound = true;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Pay attention to this flag `RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST`.

**Be aware that this implementation will not work if your array structure is invalid**. For example, if there is a child with given id, but it doesn't have an ancestor with zero-parent, it will return the next element with zero-parent.

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0eafdd318517b27e81ec1971db14ba455ce8b56).

Comment: @sevavietl thanks! But like you said I had to adjust my calls to function to handle the zero-parents.